# Linear programming: How to introduce a second decision variable (array) in Python optimization?

Tags: python, arrays, optimization, scipy, linear-programming

In `scipy.optimize.linprog(c, A_eq, b_eq)`, the resulting solution is a decision variable (array) called `x` that multiplies with array `c`.

How to admit a second decision variable (array) called `y` in the constraint vector `b_eq` and have `linprog` minimize the main objective function so that the `y` is also optimized for, not just `x`?

In other words, instead of minimizing the objective function by finding the optimal `x`array only, we want to minimize the objective function by finding the optimal `x` array *as well as* the newly introduced `y` array.

Comment: You need to concatenate / flatten them . `x0, x1, ..., y0, y1, ...`. Additionally the number of columns in the matrix is growing in parallel. This is the standard-form which always is defined on a 1d-vector x.

Comment: but `linprog` doesn't even admit the first decision variable `x` as an input. How can I even send `y` as an input, let alone tell the optimizer that I am concatenating the two? the only input sent to `linprog` is `c`. Which matrix are you saying is growing in parallel?

Comment: Can you elaborate? (when there are 3 vars, A_eq is of size `(n_constraints, 3`. Adding n vars, this becomes `3+n`.)

Comment: `x` appears nowhere in the call to the optimizer:  `scipy.optimize.linprog(c, A_eq, b_eq)`. If there's no way to define `x` in the first place, how can I possibly tell the optimizer that I am modifiying its regular form so that it's concatenated with a new decision variable `y` like what you're suggesting?

Comment: I see. It's inferred from c (or A_eq and co). As these *grow* in parallel.

Comment: so concatenation is still the way to go even though `x` is part of the objective function, while `y` appears in the constraint vector `b` as described in the question? These 2 decision variables appear in very different parts of the optimization problem, so why would concatenation still work?

Comment: Look at the standard-form. If y is not part of the objective (in your use-case), it still is (in standard form), but the coeffs are 0. Meaning, concatenation means adding 0's to c here. Same for A_eq. Adding 3 vars of y, there are 3 new coeffs needed for every constraint. The matrix gained 3 columns. Might be zero or not. Why'? Because it's the standad-form and all real solvers do *sparse algebra*.

Comment: here are more details on my particular problem where I can write the problem in math: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3929230/linear-programming-with-a-second-decision-variable-in-the-constraint-vector?noredirect=1#comment8104492_3929230