# Linear programming: How to introduce a second decision variable (array) in SCIPY optimization?

Tags: python, scipy, scipy-optimize

In  `scipy.optimize.linprog(c, A_eq, b_eq)` , the resulting solution is a decision variable (array) called  `x`  that multiplies with array  `c` .

How to admit a second decision variable (array) called  `y` in the constraint vector  `b_eq`  and have linprog minimize the main objective function so that the  `y`  is also optimized for, not just  `x` ?

In other words, instead of minimizing the objective function by finding the optimal xarray only, we want to minimize the objective function by finding the optimal  `x`  array as well as the newly introduced  `y`  array.

This same question was made a few months ago, but no answers were useful:

[Same question link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65097511/linear-programming-how-to-introduce-a-second-decision-variable-array-in-pytho/69845789#69845789)

Comment: The statements in your linked question still apply. scipy follows the standard-form and the user is responsible for flattening / merging multiple objective vectors.

Comment: Your question is already answered in the comments of your linked question...

Comment: Yes, but I could not apply those answers in practice! :(

Comment: Then look for another framework which is less low-lvl (or less algebraic / matrix-based). Python-MIP, pulp, pyomo, ... There are lots of alternatives.

Comment: Thanks sascha! I did explore Pyomo/Pulp/Ortools libraries, but those ones have some scalabilty issues because do not support numpy arrays operations. I didn´t try GurobiPy, did you?

Comment: That's broad. I would question this in general (although different libs introduce different overhead), as this is mostly about how to use those. But let me tell you, that some numpy-array only usage will also show scalability-issues with scipy. Look at the standard-form. Think about your x/y objective-vectors and how it would look like to merge those. It will be (somewhat) a block-matrix! This one has some sparsity and numpy doesn't know sparsity. It now becomes important to do sparse-algebra (scipy.sparse). This is basically the reason, why all solvers are completely based on sparse algebra.

Comment: Yes I agree. My original problem was solved with Scipy using big arrays and introducing them in the scipy.optimize with the scipy.sparse estructure. I will try that with Pyomo ! Thanks!!